# Write out without quitting in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I looked through the `vim` manual, and I could only find the commands for "write and quit" and "write (if edited) and quit". Is there a command for "write out without quitting", similar to <kbd>^o</kbd> in `nano`?

Comment: One may wonder exactly how you read the manual given that `:help write` and `:help writing` get you straight to the solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `write` command:

```
:write
```

Which can be abbreviated:

```
:w
```

If you want to write to another file without changing the current file, supply a different filename to the `write` command:

```
:write newfile
```

If you want to write to another file and change to that file, use the `saveas` command:

```
:saveas newfile
```

Which can be abbreviated:

```
:s newfile
```

Comment: And `:wa` to `:write` all opened files/buffers.

Comment: And `:w!` to force an over-write.

Comment: You may want to incorporate what the comments says to make your answer more complete.

Comment: @N.N.: The abbreviated versions should be part of the answer, but I'm not so sure about the other use-cases.